# What kind of API does Matlab's Trading Toolbox use for Interactive Brokers?

Tags: matlab, api, interactive-brokers

Noob question but I'm trying to figure out which API the Matlab Trading Toolbox uses so that I can refer to the proper guide.

The Matlab website says to refer to the Interactive Brokers API guide for details on how to implement a trading system..    http://www.mathworks.com/help/trading/ibtws.createorder.html#inputarg_ibContract

However, when I open the Interactive Broker's guide there are a few versions, such as one for ActiveX, Java, and C++. Which should I use?

https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/api.htm

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MathWorks Trading Toolbox uses IB's ActiveX API (this is the reason that it only works on Windows).
On the other hand, [IB-Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/ib-matlab) uses the Java-based API.

Comment: Thanks Yair. 

I am looking forward to IB-Matlab

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the link you provided there really isn't any information about MATLAB. I would recommend the [IB-MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/ib-matlab/usage-examples) interface at undocumented MATLAB.